# In D&D 4e powers with effects based on a stat, does 1/2 your level count for the effect?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-levels

For example: Boundless Endurance (L2 Fighter stance) says "You gain regeneration 2 + your Constitution modifier when you are bloodied."  Does this include 1/2 of your level, or just raw Con modifier? If it doesn't include 1/2 level isn't it kinda weak?

The same question applies to Sweeping Blow (Fighter attack in Player's Handbook): if a character is wielding an axe does he get an attack bonus of stat mod + 1/2 lvl?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site, Guard No. 67.  I've done editing on your question to make the title clearer; I hope this matches what you meant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're slightly confusing the *attack roll* of the power (which decides whether it hits at all) with the *effect* of the power (which decides what it does when it hits.)
The short form: No, powers don't include 1/2 your level in the effect (unless they say so).

Most powers have an *attack roll* to see whether you will hit, and this works like every other skill check: 1/2 your level plus the modifier for the ability.  In practice your total attack bonus will usually include:

- Your **base attack bonus: half your level plus the ability score modifier for the attack**.
- If it's a weapon power, your weapon proficiency bonus.
- If it's a weapon or implement power, an enhancement bonus from a magic weapon or implement (if you have one).
- Any bonuses from racial abilities or feats.
- Situational modifiers (cover, combat advantage, etc.)

(See PHB p274 or Rules compendium p215)

So yes, when Sweeping Blow says the attack is 'Strength vs AC', it means "Strength + 1/2 your level + weapon proficiency" in the attack bonus.  It doesn't say so because all powers work like this, so the 'Strength' just tells you which stat to use.

However, Boundless Endurance doesn't have an attack roll at all, it just has an effect: you gain Regeneration 2 + Con mod.  So it happens exactly as written.

(And no, it's not weak at all, it's one of the strongest L2 utility powers.  With a Constitution-focussed fighter - and who else would take that power? - it can easily give you 6 or 7 hp per round.  That's free, *without* using healing surges.  This is a big deal; healing that doesn't use up surges is very rare.  And it's only a level 2 power!  Remember that with a decent leader in the group, you could easily be getting healing surge use on top of that.

If Boundless Endurance gave 1/2 level extra, it would be massively overpowered - so good that no other level 2 choice made sense. At Epic level that would be around 22hp per round!  Without actually using up healing powers or surges.)

Comment: The real simple answer is that the 1/2 level bonus applies to d20 rolls, and only d20 rolls, except saving throws. That is, any check (an attack roll just being a specific form of check).